# Angular 8 - Pass an array of object to my component to display

Tags: typescript, pipe, angular8

I am new at Angular 8 and I am trying to simply pass an array of objects to my component to then display it in the UI.

**parent-component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  options = [
    { key: "type", value: 'Type' },
    { key: "name", value: 'Name' },
    { key: "area", value: 'Area' }
  ]
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   
  }
}
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<app-child [options]='options'></app-child>
```

**child-component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent {

  @Input() options: any[]
}
```

**child.component.html**

```
<div id="child-component>
    <select id="child-select">
        <option id="child-option-{{i}}" 
            *ngFor="let option of options | keyvalue; let i = index" 
            [value]="option.value"
        > Key: <b>{{option.key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{option.value}}</b> 
    </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

My current outcomes is:

- Key: 0 Value: [object Object]
- Key: 1 Value: [object Object]
- Key: 2 Value: [object Object]

Instead I would like something like this:

- Key: type Value: Type
- Key: name Value: Name
- Key: area Value: Area

I thought adding the pipe keyvalue would solve my problem but it doesn't.

Can someone help, please?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you need the pipe part of the ngFor `| keyvalue`.

Comment: You are actually correct - I kept changing my code and I had never tried that apparently!
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the pipe keyvalue from the child component solves my problem - thank you guys!